# Excel formulas&subtotals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this excel sheet and I have to calculate into the G column the sum of sales until a date ( in G1 the sum until 01.10.2015, in G2 until 02.10.2015, G3 until 03.10.2015 and so on). Can I make it easily and maybe automatically, without writing the formula in each cell?

[image]

Comment: In cell G3 type `=N(G2)+C3`. Then, copy this formula cell to the end.

Answer (score 0):

HYC's answer is probably the neatest you're going to see. There is an alternative method where the results are not dependent on one another, although it's less neat: In cell G3 type `=SUM(INDIRECT("c3:c"&ROW()))` and copy this formula down to the end.

Answer (score -1):

Use the SUMIF function. Check here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.